# To start pagenumbering after title and pdf-page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have the structure

```
\documentclass{article} % use prl for onepage
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{28em} \= \\ % increased the length to 15em
Supervisor: \> Instructor: \\
Prof. Me \> M.Sc. Tech. You \\
\end{tabbing}

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
\includepdf[pages={1}]{abstract_1.pdf}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

**How can you start pagenumbering after the title page and included pdf-page?**
So at the third page should be **3**.
I have at the moment **1** in the front page and **2** in the third page.
So two mistakes.

Comment: since you want a page number one greater than what is there now, after the `\clearpage`, `\stepcounter{page}` should advance the current value by one.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you! Your answer solves one problem. The other remains: to take off the pagenumber from the title page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two problems here:

- omit the page number from the title page.  this can be done by adding

  ```
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  ```

  after `\maketitle`.
- change the page number after the pdf-page (which is now 2) to 3.  this can be done
  by inserting

  ```
  \stepcounter{page}
  ```

  after the `\clearpage`.

Comment: The command **thispagestyle{empty}** should be after the command **maketitle** too.

Comment: @Masi -- you're correct, thanks. actually, only one `\thispagestyle{empty} is needed; answer corrected.